# Showing just one element on hover event jQuery

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-hover

I am creating a team section. I have a simple <div> where I have the profile photos of each member and when I hover the photo it shows you the information.
I made that happen easily with jQuery's `.hover()`. But, when I copied that same code guess what it did. Yeah, you guys are right: it shows me the information from all the team members.

What I want is simply just to display them one by one and when you stop hovering the content to return back to their initial state.

I leave my JS Code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.teamMemberPhoto').hover(function(){
        $('.teamMemberCircle').hide();
        $('.teamMemberInfo').show();
    });
</script>
```

**Edit, Added HTML:**

```
<div class="teamMembersContainer">

                        <div class="teamMember">
                            <h3 class="teamMemberName">Sarei Arlin Rodriguez Camarillo</h3>
                            <p class="teamMemberPosition">Software Developer</p>

                            <div class="teamMemberBox">

                                <div class="teamMemberCircle" style="background: #52b3d9;">

                                    <img class="teamMemberPhoto" src="../img/team/1.png" alt="Member" >

                                </div>

                                <div class="teamMemberInfo">

                                    <h4 class="teamWhat">What I do in my job?</h4>
                                    <p class="teamInfoContent">Software Development</p>

                                    <h4 class="teamWhat"> Why I do what I do ?</h4>
                                    <p class="teamInfoContent">Currently, I work in software development which is one of the most fulfilling things I have done and it has given me great personal and professional satisfaction.</p>

                                    <h4 class="teamWhat">What I do for fun?</h4>
                                    <p class="teamInfoContent">I have a great passion for the world of technology and telecommunications and love discovering and learning new about that realm.</p>


                                </div>

                            </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>
               </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share the HTML markup...

Comment: The solution depends on your HTML structure. Also, unless you have a reason not to, I suggest using CSS for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that your JavaScript code selects all elements with the class teamMemberPhoto and puts a hover function on it, that just hides -all- elements (in the whole document, not just the ones within the <div>) that have the class teamMemberCircle and shows all elements with class teamMemberInfo.

A solution is to search within the `this` element, which is always defined as the "current" element for event handler functions. Also you need to put everything inside a `$(window).load(function(){ ... });` to ensure the page has been loaded, before changing the DOM tree.

Here is the working version JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
      $('.teamMemberBox').hover(
        function(){
          $('.teamMemberCircle', this).hide();
          $('.teamMemberInfo', this).show();
        },
        function(){
          $('.teamMemberCircle', this).show();
          $('.teamMemberInfo', this).hide();
        }
      );
});
</script>
```

Also you wanted the code to let the state return to its initial state. Therefore I added the second parameter that .hover() takes (first one: "handlerIn", second is: "handlerOut"). This handler flips the state back to the original state.

A working version of your sample code can be found at: http://jsfiddle.net/jkt4b68v/1

Note: You can find the official documentation of `.hover()` at http://api.jquery.com/hover/. As the API changes with increasing revision of jQuery you should always have a look at this official page, because there are a lot of old examples in the wild that use e.g. deprecated functions that will soon cause problems.

Comment: It doesn't show the content, I put some console.log in there and it calls the event but it doesn't show the content.

Comment: Yeah, that's correct. The reason is, that I did not have your HTML when writing this answer. Your HTML structure doesnt match to the code as the elements with teamMemberCircle / teamMemberInfo are no children of the "this" element to which the event was assigned to. I currently investigate your HTML to solve this and will then post a better solution.

Comment: You are welcome! I edited my post. Let me know if the new code is working... Unfortunately, I couldn't test it.

Comment: Hot working uet :( I made a JSFiddle honestly I don't know where is the bug http://jsfiddle.net/jkt4b68v/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jkt4b68v/1/ <-- got it working. Your CSS was a bit special. So I had to put in each part of the CSS one by one and see what it actually does. Will now update my answer accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

Show html so I can have more precision to help you.

Maybe the script below solves your problem, or gives you a sense of what gotta be done.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.teamMemberPhoto').mouseover(function(){
            $(this).find('.teamMemberCircle').hide();
            $(this).find('.teamMemberInfo').show();
        }
        $('.teamMemberPhoto').mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).find('.teamMemberCircle').show();
            $(this).find('.teamMemberInfo').hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```